# How to run another workbook's macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing some code in workbook1 to open and run macro in workbook2.
Workbook_Name is the name of workbook2 with ".xlsm". I applied the following code in workbook1, hoping to run the macro "Sheet8.Compute" in workbook2. But its not working. Kindly assist.

```
ActiveSheet.Application.run "'" & Workbook_Name & "'!Sheet8.Compute"
```

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your Sub `Compute` is stored in the worksheet code of a Sheet (at least your line of code suggest that). In that case, you need to call it without the sheet name:

```
 Application.run "'" & Workbook_Name & "'!Compute"
```

However, it is good practice to put code other than event routines into a module. In that case, you can call the routine with or without the module name. Assuming module name `Module1`, you can use both:

```
 Application.run "'" & Workbook_Name & "'!Compute"
 Application.run "'" & Workbook_Name & "'!Module1.Compute"
```

Comment: I still faced "application-defined or object defined error" when i tried using Application.run "'" & Workbook_Name & "'!Compute"

Comment: I assume that the `run` command is now executed but your `Compute`-routine throws an error (else the error messages would look different).